# I want to consume an API in laravel with guzzle but I get the following ErrorException Undefined array key 1

Tags: json, laravel, api, laravel-8, guzzle

**LATER I WANT TO GET THE RESULT IN A VIEW WHERE I GET THE NAME AND IDCEDULA THROUGH A SEARCH BY IDCEDULA

DO NOT KNOW WHY IT MARKS THE ERROR **

**THIS IS THE API**

```
{
"items": [
{
"anioreg": 1991,
"carArea": null,
"carCons": null,
"carNivel": null,
"carSarea": null,
"curp": null,
"desins": "UNIVERSIDAD PANAMERICANA",
"foja": null,
"idCedula": "1629426",
"inscons": 251,
"insedo": 9,
"libro": null,
"materno": "NIETO",
"maternoM": null,
"nombre": "ENRIQUE",
"nombreM": null,
"numero": null,
"paterno": "PEÑA",
"paternoM": null,
"sexo": "1",
"tipo": "C1",
"titulo": "LICENCIATURA EN DERECHO"
}
],
"filename": null,
"idCedula": null,
"idProfesionista": null,
"sessionId": null,
"theStream": null,
"token": null,
"urlVideo": null
}
```

**THIS IS MY CONTROLLER WHERE DO I GET THE API URL THROUGH GUZZLEHTTP
I already tried json encode but it still doesn't work **

```
public function index()
        {
    
    
            $client = new Client([
                'base_uri' => 'https://www.cedulaprofesional.sep.gob.mx/',
                'timeout' => 300,
                'Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json',
                'Accept: application/vnd.api+json',
    
            ]);
    
    
    
            $response = $client->request('GET', 



"https://www.cedulaprofesional.sep.gob.mx/cedula/buscaCedulaJson.action?json=%7B%22maxResult%22%3A%2250%22%2C%22nombre%22%3A%22%27%20LUIS%20%27%22%2C%22paterno%22%3A%22%27%20HERNANDEZ%20%27%22%2C%22materno%22%3A%22%27%20GRANILLO%20%27%22%2C%22idCedula%22%3A%22%22%7D&wt=json");
    
    
            $responseData = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    
    
    
            return ($responseData);
```

Answer (score -1):

you most use POST method, not GET

#### EDIT 1

This is my JavaScript solution with Axios

```js
const axios = require("axios");

const cedula = 1629426

const result = axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: `https://www.cedulaprofesional.sep.gob.mx/cedula/buscaCedulaJson.action?json={"maxResult":"1","nombre":"","paterno":"","materno":"","idCedula":"${cedula || ""}"}`,
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    }).then((res) => JSON.parse(res.data))
```

Comment: I already tried with the POST method but the error persists